# Gábor Szegő burial location

Tags: mathematicians, death

Yesterday I saw Pólya's burial spot in Alta Mesa Memorial Park in Palo Alto, CA. Actually, it was not a grave but an urn (which gives a new meaning to the term "Pólya's urn model"). Naturally after seeing Pólya it's interesting to see where Szegő is buried, but I can't find anything about this anywhere online, not just at https://www.findagrave.com/.  Does anyone know where he was buried/cremated?  Note he was born in 1895 and died in 1985, so the one hit with his name on the find-a-grave website is not him since that Gábor Szegő is listed as having died in 2015.